# How to get result of multiple records into map int JDBC Template?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using **queryForList** to get an arrayList of the result set, like the following example :

```
List<Student> studentsList = null;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM [student]";
try {
    studentsList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Student.class));
} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
}
return (ArrayList<Student>) studentsList;
```

Now I want to get the result of this list into a map of **key** and **object** directly from the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't see you are using queryForList anywhere

Comment: What are you planning on using as a key in your map?

Comment: @mohammedkhan the id , an integer id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for you to obtain your `Map` from the query as such. You will need to manipulate your `List` returned from `jdbcTemplate.query` so that it gives you the `Map` you require with each key being the id of the student:

```
Map<Integer, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
for (Student student : studentsList) {
    studentMap.put(student.getId(), student);
}
```

If you're using java 8 you can use a [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html):

```
Map<Integer, Student> result = studentsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `queryForMap` instead of `query`. This will solve your problem if you need to map by column name.

Documentation: [queryForMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap-java.lang.String-)

Comment: isn't queryForMap used only for getting one row, not multiple rows?